# Nginx doesn't show a directory index unless I have the non-gziped index.html when I can just provide the .html.gz of other files

Tags: nginx, compression, gzip, directory-index

My site is full of pre-compressed gzip files. In all cases, except for the **index.html** file, I don't need the non-gzip versions.

For example, if I have **1.html.gz**, then I don't need to also have **1.html** on my site.

And yet, if I have an **index.html.gz** file but I don't have an **index.html**, then my site completely fails to load. Is there a way to avoid this redundancy, or do I just need to cope with it?

NOTE: If it matters at all, my server's run by NGINX.

EDIT: even if I edit  **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** to have the line **index index.html.gz**, then it'll deliver the index page as a download-only file!

Comment: Why pre-compressed?  I'm not sure all clients can handle gzip compression.  Most web servers compress on the fly.   Does nginx de-compress for clients that can't handle it?

Comment: How do you determine which file to serve?

Comment: Are you using [`Module ngx_http_gzip_static_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html)?

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller Pre-compressed is faster.

Comment: @Maximillian Laumeister Yes. All gzip files are correctly delivered.

Comment: @MrWhite NGINX will deliver index.html by default. However, even if I edit  **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** to have the line **index index.html.gz**, then it'll deliver the index page as a download-only file!